# Gridview size (appearance) changes at different searches?

Tags: asp.net, database, gridview

I have a gridview that shows some search results. But at different search results, i see different sizes of this gridview and it is not a good looking appearance. Here it is:

[image]

[image]

As you see, the sizes of heardes and rows change. Here is the code for gridview:

```
<asp:GridView ID="searchResults" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" OnSelectedIndexChanged="searchResults_SelectedIndexChanged"
    BackColor="White" BorderColor="White" BorderStyle="None" BorderWidth="1px" CellPadding="4"
    ForeColor="Black" GridLines="Vertical" style="margin-right: 0px" Width="1018px" 
                Height="192px">
    <RowStyle BackColor="#F7F7DE" />
    <Columns>
        <asp:TemplateField>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:CheckBox ID="checkboxRegister" runat="server" />
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="CRN" HeaderText="CRN" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="CourseCode" HeaderText="Course Code" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="CourseNumber" HeaderText="Course Number" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Credit" HeaderText="Credit" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="CourseName" HeaderText="Course Name" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Capacity" HeaderText="Capacity" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="InstructorName" HeaderText="Instructor" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Level" HeaderText="Level" />
    </Columns>
    <FooterStyle BackColor="#CCCC99" />
    <PagerStyle BackColor="#F7F7DE" ForeColor="Black" HorizontalAlign="Right" />
    <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#9E51CF" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
    <HeaderStyle BackColor="#564D94" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
    <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="White" />
</asp:GridView>
```

And here is how i bind the data:

```
protected void BClassSearch_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection();
        con.ConnectionString = Userfunctions.GetConnectionString();
        con.Open();
        string selected = lbCourseListBox.SelectedValue;

       if(selected!="" && Tcoursenumber.Text!="")
       {
           string query="";
           if(MyGlobals.student.getLevel()=="Undergraduate")
              query = "select [CRN],[CourseCode],[CourseNumber],[Credit],[CourseName],[Capacity],[InstructorName],[Level] from CourseTable where CourseCode='" + lbCourseListBox.SelectedValue+"' and CourseNumber = '" + Tcoursenumber.Text+"'" + "' and Level='Undergraduate";
           else
               query="select [CRN],[CourseCode],[CourseNumber],[Credit],[CourseName],[Capacity],[InstructorName],[Level] from CourseTable where CourseCode='" + lbCourseListBox.SelectedValue+"' and CourseNumber = '" + Tcoursenumber.Text+"'";

            SqlDataAdapter adap = new SqlDataAdapter(query, con);

            DataTable tab = new DataTable();

            adap.Fill(tab);

            searchResults.DataSource = tab;
            searchResults.DataBind();
       }
       else if (selected != "" && Tcoursenumber.Text == "")
       {
           string query = "";
           if (MyGlobals.student.getLevel() == "Undergraduate") 
              query = "select [CRN],[CourseCode],[CourseNumber],[Credit],[CourseName],[Capacity],[InstructorName],[Level] from CourseTable where CourseCode='" + lbCourseListBox.SelectedValue+"' and Level='Undergraduate'";
           else
               query = "select [CRN],[CourseCode],[CourseNumber],[Credit],[CourseName],[Capacity],[InstructorName],[Level] from CourseTable where CourseCode='" + lbCourseListBox.SelectedValue + "'";

           SqlDataAdapter adap = new SqlDataAdapter(query, con);

           DataTable tab = new DataTable();

           adap.Fill(tab);

           searchResults.DataSource = tab;
           searchResults.DataBind();
       }
       else if (selected == "" && Tcoursenumber.Text != "")
       {
           string query="";

           if(MyGlobals.student.getLevel()=="Undergraduate")
                query = "select [CRN],[CourseCode],[CourseNumber],[Credit],[CourseName],[Capacity],[InstructorName],[Level] from CourseTable where CourseNumber='" + Tcoursenumber.Text+"' and Level='Undergraduate'";
           else
               query = "select [CRN],[CourseCode],[CourseNumber],[Credit],[CourseName],[Capacity],[InstructorName],[Level] from CourseTable where CourseNumber='" + Tcoursenumber.Text + "'";
           SqlDataAdapter adap = new SqlDataAdapter(query, con);

           DataTable tab = new DataTable();

           adap.Fill(tab);

           searchResults.DataSource = tab;
           searchResults.DataBind();
       }
       else if (selected == "" && Tcoursenumber.Text == "")
       {
           string query = "";

           if(MyGlobals.student.getLevel()=="Undergraduate")
                query = "select [CRN],[CourseCode],[CourseNumber],[Credit],[CourseName],[Capacity],[InstructorName],[Level] from CourseTable where Level='Undergraduate' order by CourseCode";
           else
                query = "select [CRN],[CourseCode],[CourseNumber],[Credit],[CourseName],[Capacity],[InstructorName],[Level] from CourseTable order by CourseCode";

           SqlDataAdapter adap = new SqlDataAdapter(query, con);

           DataTable tab = new DataTable();

           adap.Fill(tab);

           searchResults.DataSource = tab;
           searchResults.DataBind();
       }
}
```

Can anyone tell me how to fix this? I appreciate any help here. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set width and height for each item, either like this:

```
<asp:BoundField DataField="Credit" HeaderText="Credit"  HeaderStyle-Width="100" HeaderStyle-Height="20" ItemStyle-Height="20" ItemStyle-Width="100" />
```

Or add 1(or 2) css styles and add them for each item:

```
<asp:BoundField DataField="CourseName" HeaderText="Course Name"  ItemStyle-CssClass="style1" HeaderStyle-CssClass="style" />
```

You can set only height if you need only height to be specified (obviously).